# Laravel 5.1: boot function not called

Tags: laravel-5.1

I want to validate that my model is valid when I save or update it. 
So I've created a classe called EloquentValidating from which I extend the class for all my model. 
Here is my boot function in EloquentValidating:

```
public static function boot()
{
parent::boot();

static::creating(function($item)
    {
        if(!$item->isValid()) return false; 
    });
static::updating(function($item)
    {
        if(!$item->isValid()) return false;
    });

}
```

The problem I have is that boot is never called. I have put a breakpoint in it, and it never triger. So my model is not validating before saving.

I have another project using the same logic, and it is working. The only difference I can see is the fact that I have namespace in the other project and not in this one. So the failing class is defined as

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class EloquentValidating extends Model {
```

while the working one is defined as:

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class EloquentValidating extends Model {
```

Could the namespacing cause this kind of problem, and why???
If I have to introduce namespacing, I will, but I would like to understand why it is the cause.

thanks
Benoit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to update compiled classes. Run

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

then...

```
php artisan optimize
```

If the problem persists, then do it manually removing the file `bootstrap/cache/services.json`, it will be generated automatically in the next request

Comment: didn't worked.  This system is fresh from GIT, so I had to do a composer update just before. So all the generated files are new.

Comment: ok, I've added the namespace, AND THEN did that, and then it worked.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that

Comment: Does anyone have a clue why it worked after adding the namespaces? I had the same issue and adding namespaces did the trick. I have no clue why??

Comment: @RickBrunken, it is because you need to complain `psr-4` declared in the `composer.json` of your project.